# Access is denied using a service account

Tags: powershell

I am trying run some NLB commands on a remote MachineA from MachineB and I am getting Access is denied error when using a service account. The command runs fine when I run as my account.

Initially when running commands from my local machine I was not able to run commands either. I was getting the same error. Even though I was able to do Enter-PSSession and run simple commands. But after following this [guide](http://www.travisgan.com/2014/03/enable-powershell-double-hop-remoting.html) I was able to solve it for my account. It was a double hop issue.

Now I don't know why service account won't execute these commands.

```
$userName = "domain\account"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $password
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName MachineA -Credential $Credential -Authentication Credssp
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { 
    
    Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters
    Get-NLBClusterNode MachineA
    } 
}

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.Netwo...tNlbClusterNode:GetNlbClusterNode) [Get-NlbCl 
   usterNode], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.GetNlbClusterNode
    + PSComputerName        : ComputerName
```

Additional info:
The service account is admin on the machine. I don't see any errors in the event log. When the service account logs in I see in the eventlog as

```
 Detailed Authentication Information:
                         Logon Process:        Kerberos
                         Authentication Package:    Kerberos
                         Transited Services:    -
                         Package Name (NTLM only):    -
                         Key Length:        0
```

When I do Get-WSMANCredSSP it gives me following output. Which allows me to do invoke-command using my personal account.

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WSManCredSSP
    The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/machinenameB
    ,wsman/fullyqualifiedmachinenameB,wsman/machinenameB
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer
```

Additional Info:
I found that the account type is user in active directory users and computers tool. There is not delegation tab on the user properties. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the user wasn't an admin on one of the clusterNodes in our NLB environment. What I didn't pay closer attention while doing NLB was when you remote into any clusterNode using PowerShell the account has to be an admin on all the nodes even if you aren't remoting into those other servers. So while the account was admin on one server but it wasn't on one of them so it failed with this error.